# Where in the Bible does it say angels sing?

Tags: angels, worship, art

I was recently told that man is the only one of God's creations that can sing. I thought angels also sang, but I don't know where the Bible says that.  Where in the Bible does it say that angels sing?

Comment: Welcome! This question (or one very similar to it) has already been asked, so this one may be closed as a duplicate. I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).